# JavaScript: how can I have a constantly running process for the purpose of monitoring?

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm not really sure how this can be achieved. I'm using the Clipboard API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) to read text from the user's clipboard. I want whatever the user currently has on their clipboard to show up on the page.

I can do a one-time paste just fine, but I'm not sure how to turn this into a constantly running process. I was planning on intermittently checking the user's clipboard to see if the contents have changed, and if they have, then paste that to the page. I want this to happen so long as the HTML page is open. Is this possible?

JavaScript seems to not like `while(true)` loops as whenever I've tried that the page has just crashed/become unresponsive.

Comment: A `while (true)` loop with an `await` on the `navigator.clipboard.readText()` should actually work.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you! Do you mind clarifying exactly how you were imagining `await` being used? As far as I can tell `await` is meant to be applied to functions, and I can put it on `readText()`, but I'm not sure at what point I'd do the check to see if the clipboard has changed.

Comment: According to the docs, `readText()` returns a promise, and that's what you can `await`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could listen for the `copy` event, when that is triggered you know the user has copied something from the page.

For clipboard changes that happen elsewhere, you can listen for the `onfocus` event on the window and check for clipboard changes then.

A copy in another app/webpage cannot happen without your window losing focus.

If that doesn't work, you can use [`setInterval(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) instead of an infinite loop.

Here is an example:

```
let prevClipText;

setInterval(() => {
  navigator.clipboard.readText().then(clipText => {
    if (clipText !== prevClipText) {
      console.log('clipboard content was changed to:', clipText);
      prevClipText = clipText;
    }
  });
}, 500);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my case something actually can be copied without the window losing focus, because the copying is being done by another program running on the user's computer. The intention is for the user to never have to click on the window, and instead just see the pasted text appearing in the background (if their browser is visible somewhere on the screen)

Comment: I'll look into setInterval(). Does it make sense to try and run a setInterval() function within a separate thread so as to be able to continue running other JS code? (Threading doesn't seem to be well supported natively in JS). My biggest concern is that the interval would have to be pretty short, a least once a second.

Comment: @JamesRonald In that case, you need to use the `setInterval` approach. `setInterval` doesn't block code execution, it only does that while the function is running (when it is triggered).

Comment: @JamesRonald I've edited my answer to add an example.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up an eventListener to continuously listen for the `copy` event, I would imagine this would do what you're looking to do. It would make it possible for you to continuously fire an update for the area where you want to display the copied content every time a user copies something. This of course requires a first time read when user enters the page to see if there is anything on the clipboard at that time. Set the event listener immediately after that check.

From MDN:

```
source.addEventListener('copy', (event) => {
    const selection = document.getSelection();
    event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', selection.toString().toUpperCase());
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/copy_event

Comment: That's a great idea, but unfortunately doesn't work for my particular situation as the copying will not be done on my page (in fact, it won't even be done in a browser. It'll be done by a different program on the user's PC). Thank you though, your code has still helped me.